# Can't get rid of blue line separating my two tables in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, team-foundation-server

[image: pic]

Any ideas? It's because I'm trying to combine two excel tables into one sheet.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the Team ribbon bar, which is connected to a TFS or Azure Dev Ops instance. The data in the table is based on a query, so Excel is automatically formatting the table for you. If you want to amend the formatting, copy the contents of the sheet and `paste values` into another sheet, to break the link to TFS.

If you alter the data in that sheet whilst it's still connected to TFS, one of 2 things will happen. 1, the data will refresh and you'll get raw data from TFS, undoing all your formatting. 2, you end up pushing the changes into TFS, and your team mates get angry with you for publishing updates to work items from Excel.

If you want to change what you're seeing, edit the TFS query you're using the export the data.

Note - I can tell this is a TFS query due to the `Path` column, and the data contained within the cells.

Comment: Is it not possible to change formatting of the table (choose a different design or colour,, turn off banded rows etc) without breaking it in this scenario? Genuine question, I don't use Team Foundation Server.

Comment: You're limited. It's basically an embedded power query, and it doesn't play nice with formatting. You're better off copying out to another disconnected (from TFS) worksheet, or editing your query if you want to change the result set.

Comment: By complete coincidence, I was working with some data today which is an export from the back end of an in-house Power App which has the same "Path" column and similar data format, so this issue might not be limited to TFS specifically, which means your answer might be even more useful to a wider set of users. Unfortunately SU does not seem to have a Power-Apps tag.